# sed can't find a file that obviously exists

Tags: directory, grep, path, pipe, sed

I run the following command which comments out all lines that contain the text "dlclose"

```
grep -lIR "dlclose" . | grep -v ".svn" | xargs sed -i "s/.*dlclose.*/\/\/&/g"
```

However, sed claims that the piped files don't exist:

```
sed: can't read ./Utilities/src/DynLib.cpp: No such file or directory
```

This doesn't make any sense since grep was able to find and pipe the filename.

What is going on here? Is it piped in the wrong format?

Also, as a side note, I would like to merge the two greps, but I am forced to use grep 2.5.1 which doesn't have exclude-dir

Comment: It works for me. Maybe adding "--verbose" or "-t" to the xargs switches to see exactly what xargs is trying to execute will help.

Comment: Works fine for me too so I do not know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a symlink pointing to a non-existant file, that's the error you'll get.